# How to make all fonts of my controls the same size?

Tags: swift, swiftui, fonts, size, picker

I'm creating an App with SwiftUI. In a view I have a TextEditor, Pickers and Steppers. I want the fonts to be the same.
This works:

```
let defaultTextSize: CGFloat = 20

Text("test")
 .font(.system(size: defaultTextSize))

TextEditor(text: $t)
.font(.system(size: defaultTextSize))

Stepper("\(selectedLevel)", value $selectedLevel, in: 1...7)
.font(.system(size: defaultTextSize))

//This does not work:

Picker("", selection: $selectedRarity){
                    ForEach(rarities, id: \.self) {rarity in Text(rarity.rawValue).tag(rarity)
                            .font(.system(size: defaultTextSize)) }
                    .frame(width: 70)
                    .font(.system(size: defaultTextSize))
```

The font size of the text inside the picker wont change, no matter if I use .system(size: or .font(.title) etc.

Any ideas? Even ChatGPT does not know :(

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Apple's native UI Components aren't usually fully customizable, but there are often UIKit workarounds that you can implement in your `init()`s.

In your `View` struct, you can place the following in your `init()`:

```
// Change the font size to built-in `TextStyle` types or your own types
//
// You can replace .highlighted with other types of text for the picker

UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
    [.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title)],
     for: .highlighted
)
```

For more picker customization or more advanced conditional customization, [click here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702563)

You'll probably want to create your own custom picker if you want more customization, which isn't too difficult to implement :)